# Add a File attachment feature to an existing Google form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google form at
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13bxRVQO5rEJr6dnkQL4ro2h15glJHNUe6YEzPmuwSdU/formResponse

I would like to have file upload feature at the last page of the form.

I acknowledge that it has to be done with Google Apps script, and I have a script ready at

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyEsIpckunY7lMR2zIU4o5p7bwgh4nDuKqizNn8X7E/dev

Now the road block is that these two are separate components and I am trying to figure out as to how should both of these be stitched together.

There has to be a trigger on Google form which initiates this script, so how should that be done ?

I also tried a very silly way of calling the form in a iFrame on another website, but then trying to change the elements with jQuery led me to a CORS issue, which can't be fixed.

This iframe way is present at

**server.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html')
  .setTitle('NewSchools Catapult: Invent 2015');
}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Random Work";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;    
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);

    return "File uploaded successfully ! <input type='text' value='" + file.getUrl() + "' /><p>Kindly, Copy the text and paste it in the form<br/>";

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

**form.html**

```
<body>
<div class="container1">
<div class="container2">
<h2>NewSchools Catapult: Invent 2015</h2>
<p>Invent 2015: Planning Application for new schools launching in 2016</p>
<form id="myForm">
    <label>Your Name<strong> *</strong></label>
    <input style="margin-top:2px;" type="text" name="myName" required placeholder="Enter Your Name">
    <input type="file" name="myFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" 
           onclick="this.value='Uploading..';
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
                    return false;">

</form>
<div id="output"></div>
</div>
</div>

<body>
<script>
    function fileUploaded(status) {
        document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
    }
</script>

<style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
 label { display:block; margin-left: 20px; font-size:0.90rem;}
 body {background-color:#fefefe;font-family: Verdana;}
 strong {color:red;}
 .container1 {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 640px;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:2px #eee;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:rgb(255,217,102);
  border-color:rgb(212,212,212);
  box-shadow:0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.container2 h2 {
  color:rgb(74,134,232);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size:2.460rem;
}
.container2 p {
color:rgb(140,140,140);
font-size:0.78rem;
}
#output, #output p {
  font-size:
  color:rgb(97,97,97);
}
#output input { width:550px; }
</style>
```

Comment: The iframe is present at http://udit01.koding.io/a1/

Comment: Please share your script by editing your question.

Comment: @KRR added the script

Comment: I think you cannot append the file upload feature to a form that was already created from Google form UI. The only way would be adding all your form elements, add all the required form validations and also the CSS code required in the form.html file and save it as a Standalone script. Then publish the code as a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).  Hope that helps!

Comment: @krr I do get that way out. But the form is 14 pages long. Doing that kind of stuff will take me forever. I think this is the most common feature request to Google devs. I am trying to think of a generic solution. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Well it seems that the most appropriate way out will be a work around as of now. Hence closing this question.